# How to get index of multiple arrays in a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I am trying to extract specific values from a list with 5 arrays in it. First I find the maximum value of each array and define it as maxElements. Then I try and match each element in the "test_list" with each value in maxElements to find the specific index. But I get followingg error code:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How do I fix this so I only get the index of the maximum value in each array in the list??

```
maxElements = np.amax(test_list,axis=1) 

res_list = []
for i in range(0, len(test_list)) :
    if test_list[i] == maxElements[i] :
        res_list.append(i)
```

Comment: test_list is an numpy array. If for e.g. test_list = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6]), the len(test_list) would return 2 because each array element is a reference to another 1D array. i.e. test_result[0] is reference for [1,2,3] and test_result[1] = [4,5,6]. You are actually trying to compare this reference with an integer value when you do test_list[i] == maxElement[i].

Comment: How can i compare each value in test_list  with the maxElement list then?

Comment: Have you tried out ‘numpy.argmax’? It retrieves the index of the maximum value along a given axis. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply loop over the lists, and for each list, find the index of the max value with `list.index(max_value)`. Note that this gets you only the first index of the max value, there could be more max values in the list.

```
res_list = []
for i in range(0, len(test_list)) :
    res_list.append(test_list[i].index(max(test_list[i])))
```

Also, if test_list is simply an array of lists, you could loop over it regularly without the range. So: `for list in test_list`.

Comment: Are you using numpy for this? cause im getting another error message: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: @CecilieHansen then add this line in the beginning of the for-loop: `curr_list = test_list[i].tolist()`, and replace the `test_list[i]` in the append line for `curr_list`.

Comment: somehow this just gives me the length of the test_list.. my code is currently as following 

`res_list = []

for list in dfd_sigma_values :
    curr_list = dfd_sigma_values[i].tolist()
    res_list.append(curr_list.index(max(curr_list)))` 
okay im all new to this haha im not sure how to write code in the comment section

Comment: @CecilieHansen if you print `curr_list` and `type(curr_list)` after you've created `curr_list`, what does it show? The correct lists/arrays from your list of arrays?

Comment: curr_list comes out as a list and curr_list just gives one list of all 5 arrays as one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your type of numpy array `maxElements = np.amax(test_list,axis=1)`  will return an array with one or more elements. e.g. if `test_list = ([1,2,3], [4,5,6])` then `maxElements = [3,6]`.

```
res_list = []
for i in range(0, len(test_list)) :
    if test_list[i] == maxElements[i] :
        res_list.append(i)
```

In the above code, you're trying to equate a reference type with a integer type, hence the error. Loop through each individual array contained in numpy array and compare elements as shown below.

```
res_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(test_list)) :
        for each_element in test_list[i]:
            if each_element == maxElement[i]
                res_list.append(i)
```